# Cloudstack 4.6.0 system vm are stuck in Starting state

Tags: apache-cloudstack

I just finished CloudStack 4.6.0 installation in CentOS 7 and system vms are not able to start, they are stuck in the Staring state. Hipervisor is KVM. I did download the system vm template by this:
/usr/share/cloudstack-common/scripts/storage/secondary/cloud-install-sys-tmplt -m /secondary -u http://cloudstack.apt-get.eu/systemvm/4.6/systemvm64template-4.6.0-kvm.qcow2.bz2 -h kvm -F
Please let me know what other information to provide. Thank you

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general OS/software tech support.

Comment: Can you check SSVM logs?

Answer (score 0):

been through this error and I can understand the stress :)
Just run the following command

```
sudo yum upgrade
```

And then restart cloudstack management server.
Hope this helps.